# how to get cms block value from display settings of a category

Tags: collection, category, selection

in the manage category page I have cms block which I want to update it programatically 
I guess that the attribute id to set for this is ***landing_page***

unfortunatley I don't know the function to get the landing page or get the cms block value

for example in this case **Category Listing**
how can I get that by collection?

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(17048);
```

also

```
echo $cat->getAttributeText('landing_page');
```

it doesn't show me anything

fortunately I did this!:

```
echo $cat->getlanding_page();
```

[image]

fortunately I solved part of the problem:

```
<?php include '/var/www/lenmar/mage_classes.php';?>
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category'); 
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(17048);
$cat->setlanding_page('11');
$cat->save();
?>
```

so I can set it and show that but how I can get the value for that? I mean instead of Id I want to get Category Listing value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code to retrieve cms block details

```
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(13);

$mode  = $cat->getDisplayMode();
//display mode = PAGE means, that category has a static block
if($mode == 'PAGE' || $mode == 'PAGE_AND_PRODUCTS'){
    //get static block id
    $page = $cat->getLandingPage();

    //cms block
    $cms_block = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load($page);

    //retrieve cms block data
    $title = $cms_block->getTitle(); // title of cms block
    $identifier = $cms_block->getIdentifier(); //identifier for that cms block
    $content = $cms_block->getContent(); //get entire content of cms block

    $content_data= $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($cms_block->getIdentifier())->toHtml(); // if you are using shortcodes/variables in static block.
}
```

The key point here is, the method `getLandingPage()` provides cms block id. Using this block id, we are then load cms block model and retrieves appropriate blocks information.

Hope that helps

Comment: hi ahsan, can you pls help me with this https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/330123/57334