# Move static block category

Tags: magento-1.9, category, static-block

I want move static block landing in Category. I found code in file

> /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/category/view.phtml

```
<?php elseif($this->isMixedMode()): ?>
<?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>
<?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
```

I tried copy or move `<?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>` in file 2columns-left.phtml but it does not work.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Please update your question with errors and what you have tried so far

Comment: Reviced. I get error if I move all conditional instructions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you cannot use those methods outside of the category view.phtml file.

If you want to get a categories static block content outside of this file you can use the following I based this on the answer given here by Rajeev - [how to get cms block value from display settings of a category](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32821/how-to-get-cms-block-value-from-display-settings-of-a-category)

Create a new template block add the following to your local xml

```
    <default>
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="core/template" name="category_static_block" template="page/html/category_static_block.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
```

Add the code below into your block

```
        <?php
        if (Mage::registry('current_category')):

            //get current category id
            $categoryId = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();
            //load current category model
            $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                    ->load($categoryId);

            $mode = $category->getDisplayMode();
            //display mode = PAGE means, that category has a static block
            if ($mode == 'PAGE' || $mode == 'PRODUCTS_AND_PAGE'):
                //get static block id
                $page = $category->getLandingPage();

                //cms block
                $cms_block = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load($page);

                //parse template to convert {{fields}}
                //from http://stackoverflow.com/a/5413698/156388
                $helper = Mage::helper('cms');
                $processor = $helper->getPageTemplateProcessor();
                $content = $processor->filter($cms_block->getContent());
                echo $content;

            endif;
        endif;
        ?>
```

And then echo this block out within your page template file:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('category_static_block');?>
```

Comment: I copied your code to 2columns-left.phtml and clear cache but it still does not work.

Comment: Just realised I am using the code above in a core/template block not within a page template. Ill have a look and update my answer

Comment: Ive updated my answer can you try the above and let me know if this works for you

Comment: code in local.xml put middle <config> ?

Comment: no create a file local.xml and put this within your theme files under app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/layout

Comment: I tried but it does not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30870/discussion-between-arturdvorak-and-bobadevv).

Comment: Thank you this. Fyi: it didn't work for me until I switched `PAGE_AND_PRODUCTS` around to `$mode == 'PRODUCTS_AND_PAGE'`

Comment: also it doesn't parse fields out like images that have been inserted as `{{media}}`, updating the snippet to my working version

Answer (score 1):

Add bellow code in file `2columns-left.phtml`

```
<?php if($currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category')):?>
                <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($currentCategory->getLandingPage())->toHtml();     
?><?php endif;?>
```

Comment: This one works immediately. +1. :)